# Accessing request object in src/groovy file in grails

Tags: grails

How can we access request object in `src/groovy` files in grails. Is it possible?.

I don't want to  pass request object from controller to `src/groovy` files through method parameter because it's an existing framework, is there any alternative way to do it.

I am only need request ContentType.

If getting request object is not possible in `src/groovy` then i am planning to put that in `ThreadLocal` class and get there, is this a good idea?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the content type? Although w/o knowing what you're actually doing I wonder if you're taking the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your point about this being an existing framework - whether you change it to pass in the request or to access it in a more convenient way, you're still changing it, right?

There's already a ThreadLocal to hold this. Add this import

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
```

and then you can access the request as

```
def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
```

Comment: @burt can you please tell where to put this code? I am trying a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638637/passing-session-value-from-controller-to-src-groovy-class/24638718#24638718

Comment: When i import this i got the follow error...... Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.