# Passing session value from controller to src/groovy class

Tags: session, grails, groovy, controller

I have set a variable in my controller class in session as follows:

```
    session.webURL = webURL
    println "#####" + session.webURL`
```

Now, I want to use this value of webURL in my src/groovy class. So I wrote in my src/groovy BasicCrawler class:

```
    println session.webURL
```

It shows me an error: Message: 'No such property: session for class: cmsprofiler.BasicCrawler' at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the session in any arbitrary class.  You can pass the value as an argument to a method in BasicCrawler if you like.

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy 
package demo
class DemoController {
    def someAction() {
        def crawler = new BasicCrawler()
        crawler.someMethod(session.webURL)
    }
}

// src/groovy/demo/BasicCrawler.groovy
package demo
class BasicCrawler {
    def someMethod(String url) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using crawler4j and I need to use the value of webURL inside the visit function. I cannot change the method definition since it needs to override the methods of crawler4j and I cannot define a function within a function as well. Any other approach?

Comment: Can you please suggest some other approach?

Comment: Pass it as an value to the constructor and then call the method